# Group of units of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the group of units of $C[0,1]$ cyclic?

I think it is not cyclic. The first argument that came to my mind is that if it is cyclic then its generator must be a constant function, but not all units of $C[0,1] $ are constant.

Is my argument correct or do we have some better argument then this?

Comment: I think it may clarify to write how the group $C[0, 1]$ is defined. I am guessing that it is the group of real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ under point-wise addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every cyclic group is finite or coubtable infinite and your group of units is uncountable.